# Remove all <div tags with SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have table name `wp_posts` and in `post_content` column there is a description of my posts (in HTML).

I would like to have a query that searches in post_content column and selects the tag starting with `<div class` or no `class>` and remove whole tag.

I dont want to remove anything inside the tag, just remove the tag

This :

```
<div> or <div clas="sada">
some text
</div>
```

Would become this:

```
some text
```

My MYSQL version is 15.1.

Comment: Your MySQL is too old, and it does not implement either regexp repalce or iterative queries. If MySQL upgrade is not an option then the only reasonable solution is stored procedure or user-defined function.

Comment: I guess the other option would be to select the rows you want to change and then do the change (ie remove the tag) with some programming language and then update the rows. Or you could use a text editor (I use vim) to find the tags and replace them with nothing. Then update the modified data into the table from the command line using your text file.

Comment: @Akina I upgrade MySQL to version 15.1, is there any solution now?

Comment: *My MYSQL version is 15.1.* MySQL does not know about such version, current actual is 8.0.28... show complete output for `SELECT VERSION();`.

Comment: @Akina 5.5.5-10.5.15-MariaDB (using this $mysqli->server_info)

Comment: MariaDB is not MySQL (it is a fork of MySQL, and now the difference is significant enough). See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/regular-expressions-functions/

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can write a short script which fetch all wp_posts elements. Then
you iterate this collection and remove with reg. expression function the div
tags and update the field again in your database.

This would be the expression which remove the div tag.
`$wp_content = preg_replace('/\<[\/]{0,1}div[^\>]*\>/i', '', $wp_content);`

Comment: I upgrade MySQL to version 15.1, can I use this  `preg_replace` in SQL query? how?

Comment: @Heisenberg *can I use this preg_replace in SQL query?* No. MySQL does not know about such function. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 0):

if you are using wordpress, you must have php access, so you can use strip_tags() to remove the html from the variable.

Comment: strip_tags() is removing all the tags, I want to remove only div tags.

Comment: @Heisenberg *strip_tags() is removing all the tags* See function description, `allowed_tags` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71124744/remove-all-div-tags-with-a-query#71125020), write it here for others:

```
update wp_posts
set post_content = REGEXP_REPLACE(post_content, '</?div.*?>', '');
```