# Remove all <div> tags with a query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

I want to remove all `<div>`  tags from content, I use this query and it removes only `<div>` tags with no class, how to remove all `<div>,<div class"example">,</div>` ?

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET `post_content` = REPLACE (`post_content`, '<div>', '') WHERE `ID`=84259
```

I want a query that removes `<%div%>` (% means no mater what is before and after div)

Comment: You should use PHP function or class such as [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead. That task is not recommend to do in MySQL/MariaDB, or any DB.

Comment: SQL is one of the worst places you can choose to do string processing.  If you have any option to do this outside of the DB, I'd recommend doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
update wp_posts
set post_content = REGEXP_REPLACE(post_content, '</?div.*?>', '');
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=8b6f5bdfe58f581d2a5ed1e89560c9b5)